# Using Tobit model to model right censored data

Tags: r, regression, model, tobit-regression

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
WEIGHT Y        X1      X2           X3
24     700000   519000  0            582119.7023
16     600000   481000  250          749498.3144
22     550000   487000  0            436589.7767
12     550000   370800  0            547319.5276
4      800000   499000  400          260192.7265
13     530000   316400  0            436589.7767
19     1000000  720000  2000         727649.6279
```

In this data, the `Y` column is right-censored at 1,000,000, meaning that we know each observation reported as 1,000,000 is **at least** 1,000,000 but its true value could be anywhere from 1,000,000 to Infinity.

I'm using the package `VGAM` and my current model looks like this:

```
fit = vglm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, family = tobit(Upper = 1000000), data = mydata, weights = WEIGHT)
```

Here are the coefficients for `fit`:

```
 (Intercept):1  (Intercept):2   X3             X1             X2
  7.118557e+05   1.240009e+01  -3.633811e-02  -9.568791e-02   2.622043e+01
```

When I apply these coefficients to my original values, I only get values for `Y` in the 650,000 - 850,000 range. Is it possible to create a model that will **only** give me estimates of greater than 1,000,000 for my top-coded values?